# Como hacer una consulta dinámica desde un JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Estoy realizando una consulta en PHP, la cual debo filtrar según los datos que obtengo de un Json. Ejemplo, recibo un Json de este tipo:

```
[ {1:pera}, {2:manzana}, {3:naranja} ]
```

y necesito que el SELECT dependa de estos datos provenientes del Json, es decir, debo pasar esas variables del Json a mi consulta (con el fin de que los campos consultados sean dinámicos) para quedar de esta forma:

```
SELECT pera, manzana, naranja FROM tabla
```

Adjunto código de mi intento hasta ahora

```
  public function downloadData(Request $request){

    $ids = [];
    $seleccion = [];

    foreach($request->values as $element){
        $ids[]=$element["id"];
        array_push($seleccion, $element["id"]);
    }

    // lo anterior retorna $seleccion=[ {1:pera}, {2:manzana}, {3:naranja} ]

    $seleccion_procesada = implode("','",$seleccion);

    // luego de procesar $seleccion_procesada=[ 'pera', 'manzana', 'naranja' ]
    
    $whereStatment = self::prepareFechaHoraQuery($request->startDate, $request->endDate, $request->minutes);

    $data = ViewResumenAgrourbana::select('FechaHora',$seleccion_procesada) //aqui no renoce los nombre de las columnas, pero escritas manualmente no hay problema (Ej: 'pera','manzana','naranja')
                                    ->whereIn('FechaHora', $whereStatment)
                                    ->orderBy('FechaHora', 'DESC')
                                    ->get();
    
    return ApiResponseController::respond(200, "Consulta exitosa", $data);

}
```

Esto arroja el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pera','manzana','naranja' in 'field list'

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Deberias agregar lo que has intentado.

Comment: @alanfcm acabo de agregar lo que he intentado hasta ahora. Gracias.

Comment: Intenta con `$seleccion_procesada = implode("', '",$seleccion);`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías convertir la cadena JSON en un arreglo con la función `json_decode` y posteriormente unir los valores con `join`

```
$items = json_encode($stringJSON, true); //devuelve un array si el JSON es correcto
$selection = join(',', $items); //une los valores del arreglo (pera,manzana...)
$sql = "SELECT ".$selection." FROM ..."; //concatenas a la consulta
```